# Shimano STx rc 8515 rd mc38 rear derailleur , what replacement jockey wheels will fit on this

Tags: derailleur-rear

As they do not make the pulley wheels for this derailleur  anymore because it’s old can you please tell me what  modern Shimano pulley wheel will fit this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any jockey wheels with the same number of teeth from the Shimano range or an aftermarket replacement. I believe these had 9 tooth pulleys but usually 10 tooth will work very nicely as a replacement too.